# My React application is running on React 17, while updating to latest React 18 version

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-datepicker, react-intl, react-calendar

My React application is running on React 17, while upgrading to latest React 18 version, below packages were upgraded with latest version, due to that not able to see the buttons and icons with below packages, after reverting with older version of below packages, my application seems good.
"react-bootstrap": "^2.9.1",
"react-bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.3",
"react-calendar": "^4.6.1",
"react-csv": "^2.2.2",
"react-datepicker": "^4.23.0",
"react-intl": "^6.5.5",
"react-redux": "^8.1.3",
"react-responsive": "^9.0.2",
"react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
"react-router-dom": "^6.19.0",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
"react-slick": "^0.29.0",
"react-table": "^7.8.0",

While running my react app not able to see the buttons and icons, with latest version packages.

Need an help while upgrading the packages are those were on sync and interlinked with each other.